# The best epoch has a higher valdation score compared to training score

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

[image]

- Model : 3D CNN regularized with autoencoder
- Data : 3D MRI image data, 804 Training Set(Data Augmentation applied, 78 -> 804), 12 Valdiation Set(no aug), 12 Test Set(no aug).

In general the epoch of highest val score is selected, but in the above result the best epoch has a higher validation score compared to training score. **In this case, is it okay to select the 2nd epoch?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it’d be a sensible way, but since your validation set is small, there can be huge variance in your selection. The difference in the score between training and validation sets is a sign of this. Based on your loss curves, second epoch seems a bit early. Fifth  or sixth epoch is better because the success/scores of validation and training sets are similar, which might suggest it’ll also be similar in the test set, i.e. better generalisation. As a final note, you may want to think of increasing your validation set a bit.